# classic asp :error '800a0bcd' load page

Tags: asp-classic

I have a problem loading the page I have a similar error message actually a lot here on the site the same time each line is a different problem message is:

> Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record: line 60 attaches to the line.

line 60:

```
SelectedCategoryID = RSCategories("CategoryID")
```

Answer (score 2):

Before using recordset data, always perform a check if recordset is not eof e.g.

```
if not RSCategories.eof then
 SelectedCategoryID = RSCategories("CategoryID")
end if
```

Comment: hii First of all, thank you.
I think it worked because I have another message: /footer.asp, line 13
   <% = BottomPage%>

Comment: Please note that this happens when your recordset is empty. If you are sure that your recordset should not be empty, double check your sql statement and **where** clause.

Comment: Besides, Welcome to stackoverflow. You can accept an answer by checking the check mark beside answer.